# Are Theodore Gray's all images copyrighted?

Tags: images

The site http://periodictable.com/ has a lot of great images. Allmost all images excluding a few have 'Copyright © Theodore W. Gray' watermark on them. So the ones which don't have this watermark, Are they free?

Comment: Depending on the country of origin and first publication, yes it is probable that they are the subject of both implicit and explicit (registered) copywrong, and will remain so until the term expires ir the evil copywrong system is overthrown.

Comment: How does this relate to computers or software as in the help section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not think that the lack of a Copyright mark renders them free. In most jurisdictions copyright is automatic as work is created.

Comment: So, can i use the ones without copyright in my android app or for any other work?

Comment: @ChinmayDabke, no that is the opposite of what he is saying. you may NOT use them, unless you get a license from the creator. they do not have to marked as copyrighted for you to be sued over them.

Comment: No, unless you find the author (or current owner) and ask him to give you a grant on write. An android app would not even justify "fair use".

Comment: As an example: See the image in this blog post: http://fantaciones.blogspot.com/2012/06/el-reino-de-saban-grecie.html The image has no copyright printed on it, nor in the metadata. But the image is mine, I drawed it in 2012, so I have Copyright on it and I will sue you if you reproduce it. But at the end of the blog you find a License where I give you some rights about the entries. If you find something similar in the webpages were you get the images from, you can use them. Otherwise, you can not.

Comment: @Envite For instance can i use this image : http://periodictable.com/Elements/013/index.html

Comment: @ChinmayDabke - We cannot determine that.  Contact the actual author of the image in order to determine that.

Comment: How is this relevant to SU?

Comment: copyright is relevant to absolutely every topic related to computing. saying otherwise is ignoring the evil of imaginary property. not saying this is a good question, but also no reason to close it since its already answered/accepted. closing it now would just be  vindictive and mean-spirited.

Comment: @ChinmayDabke No, you can not use that Aluminium image. It has copyright, and you need to contact its copyright owner (which is difficult since it is unknown) before using it. You can, however, take note of the current year and use it with total safety in now+95 years